# Java TextField question

Tags: java, regex, swing, text, field

I am trying to build a custom text field class that accepts lengths (the span of aircraft wings, for example).  I can set default unit system such as "inches", "feet", "meters" etc. but I would also like to be able to input lengths that are not in the default unit system.

So for example, if my default unit system is "meters", I would like to be able to input "10.8 ft" in my text field and then convert from ft to meters.

Does anyone know if there is an example of this type of coding? I have searched and found a text field that only accepts numerics (in [NumericTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/NumericTextField.htm)), but this does not suit my needs because I would like to input "10 ft" or "8.5 m".

Comment: I would think a better design would be to have the text field for inputing the number and then have a combo box to select the unit. That way you don't have to worry if people put "ft" or "feet" etc.

Comment: camcikr is right. that would be more intuitive too

Comment: Also, that link is old. A better way to implement a number text field is to use a JFormattedTextField or use a DocumentFilter.

Comment: for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548167/make-custom-jtextfield-jcurrencyfield/6551641#6551641

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
public class MyCustomField extends JPanel
{
    public static final int METER = 1;
    public static final int FEET = 2;
    private int unit_index;
    public JTextField txt;
    public JLabel label;
    public MyCustomField(int size, int unit_index)
    {
        this.unit_index = unit_index;
        txt = new JTextField(size);
        ((AbstractDocument)txt.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new MyFilter());
        switch(unit_index)
        {
            case METER:
            label = new JLabel("m");
            break;

            case FEET:
            label = new JLabel("ft");
            break;

            default:
            label = new JLabel("m");
            break;
        }
        add(txt);
        add(label);
    }
    private class MyFilter extends DocumentFilter
    {
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()));
            sb.insert(offset, text);
            if(!containsOnlyNumbers(sb.toString())) return;
            fb.insertString(offset, text, attr);
        }
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()));
            sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);
            if(!containsOnlyNumbers(sb.toString())) return;
            fb.replace(offset, length, text, attr);
        }
        private boolean containsOnlyNumbers(String text)
        {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.?\\d*");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            return matcher.matches();
        }
    }
}
```

I made this qucikly. You can improve it by adding more methods and units if you need.

Answer (score 1):

[`JScience`](http://jscience.org/) provides support for strongly typed physical quantities and operations in [`org.jscience.physics.amount`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/physics/amount/package-summary.html#package_description).